# What should I use to mount a camera to a wall, with the option to swivel and tilt?

Tags: equipment-recommendation

We need a solution to mount a camera to a wall. We'd like an option that swivels and tilts, which [this option](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002OREONQ) does. This option uses a vise to mount, which means we need to install something into the wall to attach the vise to. Does anyone have ideas? Or another solution that is effective for our goal?

Answer (score 3):

There's a [wall mount system](http://www.adorama.com/BG3277.html) available at Adorama that sounds exactly like what you're looking for.

Also, depending of the surface and the use you are planning on, a [suction mount](http://www.adorama.com/catalog.tpl?op=itemlist&cat1=Tripods&cat2=Specialized%20Camera%20Supports&cat3=Suction%20Mounts) might be a good option too, since it wouldn't require any holes in the wall.

Answer (score 0):

First thought that came to my mind: [Umbra Conceal Wall Book Shelf](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000IVRTBO).

Those things are pretty cool to just see a pile of books floating on a wall. They should be able to more than handle the weight of a small camera on that device.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of cheep wall mounts designed for security cameras, generally they are small, cheep and can swivel and tilt.

Here are two example products in this category: [A simpler mount ($6)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000IDBXBO), [A more complex system ($8)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000IDCDZY)

They should be able to support a compact camera, consumer video camera and maybe even a small DSLR without any problem (but I wouldn't try to mount a larger DSLR or a camera with an heavy tele lens on them).

They do require drilling